# jQuery change value of select list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code

```
<select id="practice_id" name="practice" column="practice" style="width: 200px">
 <option value="">Default</option>
 <option value="1">Test 1</option>
 <option value="2">Test 2</option>
 <option value="3">Test 3</option>
 ...............
</select>
```

What I need to do, is to change the value of the selected item to one based on a query string number (I can get this value ok)

I am trying to change the value using jQuery, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

```
$('#practice_id').val('QUERY_STRING_NUMBER');
```

This doesn't seem to work as the value doesn't change.

I am I getting something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: probably you can remove the currently selected option and replace it with an <option value="QUERY_STRING_NUMBER">?

Comment: @DG3 Or just [change the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032142/jquery-change-value-of-select-list/10032258#answer-10032258) :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to select the `option` element and not the `select` element:

```
(function($) {
    $('#practice_id').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);
        $('option[value=' + val + ']', this).val('changed');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/6yre7/

Answer (score 1):

`$('#practice_id').val('QUERY_STRING_NUMBER');`

This is setting the value of the dropdown, not "changing" the underlining  option value.

`$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#practice_id").children().val("-99");
});`

This will change the value to -99 on all of the option tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/MejLX/1/

**Note:** Yes, you can do this via jQuery. However, based on most everyday common scenarios I would think that your server-side script/page would be generating the correct value.

Comment: Is there a way to change option value?

Comment: Sorry about the updates as something weird was going on with the editting.